# SQL - How to select all Chats and order them by most recent Message

Tags: sql

I am creating a simple Chat application and I would like to select all `Chat` and order them by their most recent `Message` (column `created_on`) .
The 2 tables are separated and are described as the following:

`CHAT`
[image]

`MESSAGE`
[image]

To achieve that, I wrote the following SQL Script:

```
SELECT * CHAT AS chat LEFT JOIN MESSAGE AS message ON chat.ID = message.CHAT_ID
GROUP BY chat.ID
ORDER BY message.CREATED_ON
```

When I run that script, the result are not ordered by **most recent** `Message` but instead randomly.
And I also noticed that the Script is not fast.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is malformed, because you are using `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY`.  (And this ignores the other syntax errors such as the missing `FROM` clause.) Your query should be returning an error.

You seem to not only want the chats to be ordered but to also include the most recent message.  For that, use window functions:

```
SELECT c.*, m.*
FROM chat c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT m.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.chat_id ORDER BY m.CREATED_ON DESC) as seqnum
      FROM MESSAGE m
     ) m
     ON c.ID = m.CHAT_ID AND m.seqnum = 1
ORDER BY m.CREATED_ON DESC;
```

In most databases, an index on `message(chat_id, created_on)` would help.

Comment: Thanks. your query does exactly what I want. But is there a way to achieve the same result without `windows functions` ? Because I am using the **NodeJS** library **TypeORM** and the subquery after the `LEFT JOIN` seen not to be supported.

Comment: @Manu . . . The alternatives would all use subqueries.